# plt.axvline labels exceeding limit of plot problem

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWXVi.png) - clearest image, shows the labels extending out the right of my plot

["zoomed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbggR.png) - highlighting why this is a problem as the plot becomes unreadable when selecting and plotting subset of the x-axis range

I'm working on some data where I have plotted a spectrum and have added vertical lines to specific positions. I have labelled these lines but my problem is that if I want to "zoom in" by decreasing my x axis range, the full list of labels for the vertical lines are still plotted resulting in an unreadable plot.

I iterate through a list of x positions and labels for my vertical lines and plot as follows:

```
for x_pos, label in zip(list_x_pos, list_label):
    plt.axvline(x=x_pos)
    plt.text(x_pos, y, str(label), rotation=90)

plt.xlim(2, 5)
```

So, because my "x values" go > 5 the resulting plot is a tiny figure with a row of the labels extending out from it.

The only solution I can think of is to slice my list_x_pos but this will crate other problems for me so ideally looking to find a way to just show the labels within the range of the plot.

Hope I've made sense!

Thanks,

Olie

Comment: Could you please link to an image? I'm having trouble understanding what's happening.

Comment: Hi Francisca, I've tried to add some images. For some reason they don't show up well when viewed in the link but are fine if you save them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.text(..., clip_on=True)` to force texts outside of the box to **not** be displayed.

Comment: Ah! So simple! Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

Resize the axes first and then plot the vertical line.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to be able to clearly see where the vertical lines match (or don't!) data in the plot. Plotting the full range means I can't identify see this unfortunately. Hence why i'm resizing the axis with the small x-range